# SQL query to select the minimum amount of boxes

Tags: sql

I have boxes containing the same item in different sizes.

```
  Boxes             S   M   L   XL  XXL

00001               2   4   4       
00002                           4   2
00003               8               
00004                   8           
00005                       8   8   
00006                               8
00007               1   2   2   2   2
00008               1   2   2   2   
00009               2   4   4   4   2
00010               3   5   4   4   2
00011               2   3   4   4   2
```

Now, I need to get the model in this sizes:

```
                    S   M   L   XL  XXL
                    2   4   4   4   2
```

What boxes do I need to cover my necessities?

I could use boxes 00003, 00004, 00005, 00006, this way, I would gather:

```
                    S   M   L   XL  XXL
                   8   8    8   8   8
```

but lot of items would be wasted.

I could also use boxes 00007, 00008 and get:

```
                    S   M   L   XL  XXL
                   2   4    4   4   2
```

Which fits me, but still, I have to move 2 boxes, meanwhile BOX 00009 has exactly what I need, with minimun effort.

To sum up, what is the minimun amount of boxes I need to cover my necessities?
I cant find a start point to build a query or some kind of code solve this out. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sounds quite like a [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem).

Comment: What's your DBMS? Also, are there any performance constraints you need to meet?

Comment: Hello, 
The bin packing problems sounds scary, but also interesting. I have faced some problems in the past related to it, so it will be useful for me, thank you kaiz.net.

Branko, 
I use mysql, and MS access as alternative front-end. No constraints

Answer (score 0):

The following will work on SQL-Server to solve your problem. It works by using a recursive CTE to determine the number of each size for **ALL** combinations of boxes (for a large amount of boxes this may get cumbersome and require the `MAXRECURSION` altering). It then determines which of these combinations satisfy the criteria of the minimum number of each size, then ranks the remaining combinations in order of number of boxes required, then the total number wasted to meet the minimum criteria. Changing the order by in the `RANK()` function will change how the solutions are ranked.

```
DECLARE @S INT = 2,
        @M INT = 4,
        @L INT = 4,
        @XL INT = 4,
        @XXL INT = 2


CREATE TABLE #Boxes (Model VARCHAR(5), S INT, M INT, L INT, XL INT, XXL INT)
INSERT #Boxes VALUES
    ('00001', 2, 4, 4, 0, 0),
    ('00002', 0, 0, 0, 4, 2),
    ('00003', 8, 0, 0, 0, 0),
    ('00004', 0, 8, 0, 0, 0),
    ('00005', 2, 0, 8, 8, 0),
    ('00006', 2, 0, 0, 0, 8),
    ('00007', 1, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    ('00008', 1, 2, 2, 2, 0),
    ('00009', 2, 4, 4, 4, 2),
    ('00010', 3, 5, 4, 4, 2),
    ('00011', 2, 3, 4, 4, 2)

;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  *, CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), Model + ';') [Models], 1 [Boxes]
    FROM    #Boxes
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  a.Model, 
            a.S + b.S, 
            a.M + b.M, 
            a.L + b.L, 
            a.XL + b.XL,
            a.XXL + b.XXL,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(1000), b.Models + a.Model + ';'), 
            Boxes + 1
    FROM    #Boxes a
            INNER JOIN CTE b
                ON a.Model > b.Model
), CTE2 AS
(   SELECT  Models, 
            S, 
            M, 
            L, 
            XL, 
            XXL, 
            Boxes, 
            (S + M + L + XL + XXL) - (@S + @M + @L + @XL + @XXL) [Wasted]
    FROM    CTE
    WHERE   S >= @S
    AND     M >= @M
    AND     L >= @L
    AND     XL >= @XL
    AND     XXL >= @XXL
)
SELECT  *,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Boxes, Wasted) [Rank]
FROM    CTE2

DROP TABLE #Boxes
```